# What is wrong with my proof that every even function must have an even primitive?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a integrable even function. Then: $f(-x) = f(x)$. Let $F(x)$ be a primitive function of $f(x)$. Then $F'(x) = f(x)$.

Plugging $-x$ into $F'(x)$: $$F'(-x) = f(-x) = f(x)$$

Take the indefinite integral of both sides: $$\int F'(-x)dx = \int f(x)dx$$

yields: $$F(-x) = F(x) + C$$
For $C=0$ we have: $$F(-x) = F(x)$$
which means that that $f$ has an even primitive. But since I know from my textbook that an even $f$ must have an odd primitive and that every two primitives of the same function differ by a constant, then we have an even and an odd function that differ by a constant. This is impossible, besides trivial functions so there must be a mistake in my proof. I have a feeling it's pretty obvious, but I just don't see it. I hope you can help me find it. Thanks.

Comment: Try an example such as $f(x)=x^2$ to spot your sign issue

Comment: You have to use the chain rule. Sometimes it's called integration by substitution.

Comment: ' But since I know from my textbook that an even f must have an odd primitive' this is a wrong notion. for eg. primitive of cosx is sinx+c ehich is odd only if c=0.

Comment: @RamanujanXV I said "an odd", which means that at least one exists.

Comment: Your handling of the constant is also problematic, you cannot just choose $C=0$. You can however plug in $x=0$ to see that $C$ must be $0$.

Comment: @CarstenS Why can't I choose any $C$? It's any real number, so I don't think it's invalid to look at the case $C=0$.

Comment: After you fixed the sign, do you think $F(-x) = - F(x) + C$ is true for all $C$? That would not be possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When going from
$$\int F'(-x)dx = \int f(x)dx$$
to
$$F(-x) = F(x) + C$$
you are claiming that $F(-x)$ is a primitive of $F'(-x).$
But by the Chain Rule,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} F(-x)
= F'(-x) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (-x)
= -F'(-x).
$$
So $F(-x)$ actually is a primitive of $-F'(-x),$ and you should now be able to show that $-F(-x)$ is a primitive of $F'(-x).$

In short, you have made a sign error, and this is why you think you have an even primitive when actually you have an odd primitive.

Answer (score 4):

$\int F'(-x)dx =-\int -F'(-x)dx=-F(-x)= \int f(x)dx$